# Setting a default state for a variable

Tags: javascript

I need to set a default value for 3 variables, the variables parent 4, 5 and 6:

```
var parentIsFull = function (tree, index) {
    var parent = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent);
    var parent2 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent2);
    var parent3 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent3);
    var parent4 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent4);
    var parent5 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent5);
    var parent6 = getParentIndex(tree, _talents[tree][index].parent6);

if (parent4 && parent5 && parent6 && (_state[tree][parent4]) + (_state[tree][parent5]) + (_state[tree][parent6]) < 8) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}

};
```

At the moment they all seem to have a default value that isn't a number, I'm guessing it is "undefined", they all need to be defined to have a value of 0 before they are changed by any other code.

What should happen is that if none of the values are changed it should `return false`
BUT as it is, if I dont change all 3 values to atleast 1 it returns true.

I'll show you what I mean, the "box" that has 4, 5 and 6 as parents is marked in red, the parents 4, 5 and 6 is marked with yellow, ergo red box = child box, yellow boxes = parent boxes:

[image]

Now adding a value of 1 to each of the parents, it correctly goes to return false, shown by greyed out text. It goes to return false because they now all have a value of 1, and collectively are still below 8:

[image]

To show the `< 8` part of my code works, you can see that as soon as the sum of the 3 parent values are changed to anything that is equals to or greater than 8 it will go to the else statement and `return true`, ergo the "red box" becomes available again:

[image]

**So I need to set a default value of 0 for all of the parents so that if they remain unchanged it will still `return false`**

That is my problem, feel free to hit me with any critique, I am still extremely new at this.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to proceed depends on all the possible value types that can be returned by your called functions.

If only falsy values and numbers are returned, you can do something like:

```
var parent = functionCall() || 0;
```

If any value can be returned and you need only numbers and all other values to be defaulted to zero, you will have to make your test in two steps like:

```
var result = functionCall();
var parent = typeof result === 'number' ? result : 0;
```